# 2 different SSL Certificates (and servers) on 1 webpage

Tags: ssl, https

I need to know if it is possible to have a webpage secured with SSL to be to able to fetch an image on a different server also secured with a potentially different SSL certificate? Difficult or trivial? Battling to find a real world way of testing this setup so I'm asking here.

Further explanation...

page under SSL (`https://their-server.com/theirPage.html`) to to call an image script (c# server-page delivering an image) e.g. `<img href="https://my-server.com/image.ashx?id=1" />`, but my server CANT use the other server's SSL certificate...

Is the mix of SSL certificates going to cause any problems or popups that will intimidate the user or make it look unsecure in any fashion?

Comment: Did you actually try this yet? A few seconds testing with a browser would have told you without any need to ask anyone else…

Comment: Thanks @DonalFellows, yeah I did, when I asked the question I couldn't simulate the scenario, but then I linked to a hotmail.com image i found with a https url, and baked a home made certificate, browser only complained that my certificate wasn't from a known source, no complaint that I was requesting 2 images from different https servers with different ssl certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the images you are loading are loaded over *some* sort of secure connection, it doesn't matter at all what certificate is used.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said the server from which you are accessing images is already secure with SSL right? Now it doesn't matter which SSL they are using.

I don't think you will have any problem in fetching that images !